# Multiple Instances test using junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a java server on a server socket. Clients connect to this server socket, and exchange over input/output object streams. Now I need to test the app for scalability. Which means I need to run the same test making requests, and test if the server is able to handle requests from random clients.

Is the below junit based test case the right way to test random connections/requests. I get a feeling that the below code is testing clients sequencially.

Some links I read, and did not work for me

[Creating a JUnit testsuite with multiple instances of a Parameterized test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227827/creating-a-junit-testsuite-with-multiple-instances-of-a-parameterized-test)

```
public class ScalePostiveTestCases {
SendQueue sendQueue;
Socket clientSocket = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {       
    testSearching() ;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static void testSearching() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    TestSuite tests = new TestSuite();
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
        Class<SingleSearchTest> singleSearchTest = (Class<SingleSearchTest>) ClassLoader
                .getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(
                        "SingleSearchTest");

        SingleSearchTest singleSearch = singleSearchTest.newInstance();
        tests.addTest(singleSearch);
    }
    TestRunner.run(tests);
}
public class SingleSearchTest extends TestCase {
    static SingleSearchTest singleSearch    = null;
    private String          device, connection, user;
    private ClientSession   clientSession;
    private SendQueue       sendQueue;

    public static SingleSearchTest main(String args[]) {
        singleSearch = new SingleSearchTest();
        return singleSearch;
    }

    public SingleSearchTest() {
       super("testSingleSearch");
       Random rand = new Random();
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps this may help you http://clarkware.com/software/JUnitPerf.html

Comment: Tried out JunitPref, its not good enough since it does not create those test's for you automatically. If I create the tests in a thread, it will be run sequentially and not in parallel. Too much work, ExecutorService is much better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating many test which have one client each.

What you need to do is have one plain test which creates many clients which are executed concurrently.

---

In my unit tests;

- start the server as a separate thread (so I can also shut it down)
- use an ExecutorService as a Thread pool for the clients
- have a loop to create all the tasks which each create a client and exercise them. When finished return from the task.
- shutdown the ExecutorService.
- go through all the tasks and check they passed. If they threw and error, the error will be thrown in the current (testing) thread.

Comment: Oh yeah, thats perfectly understood. The question is how ?

Comment: Thanks Peter. This helped. public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        SingleClientTest clientTest = new SingleClientTest();
        threadExecutor.execute(clientTest);
    }
    threadExecutor.shutdown();
    while (!threadExecutor.isTerminated()) {
    }
}

Comment: You can use `threadExecutor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);` which avoids the need to busy wait (and burn a CPU) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that I was using threadExecutor.isTerminated and threadExecutor.showdown, instead of using threadExecutor.isShutDown and threadExecutor.shutdownNow. I also tried threadExecutor.awaitTermination. Worked. Basically both tests run in parallel.

```
public static void testLoading() {
    threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        SingleClientTest clientTest = new SingleClientTest();
        randomStringList.add(clientTest.getRandomString());
        threadExecutor.execute(clientTest);
    }
    threadExecutor.shutdownNow();
    try {
        threadExecutor.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
//      while (!threadExecutor.isShutdown()) {
//      }
}
public static void testSearching() {
    threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        SingleSearchTest searchTest = new SingleSearchTest(randomStringList);
        threadExecutor.execute(searchTest);
    }
    threadExecutor.shutdownNow();
    try {
        threadExecutor.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
//      while (!threadExecutor.isShutdown()) {
//      }
}
```